# XOR of 2 numbers in given range which is smaller than or equal to K

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit, xor, bitwise-xor

Given two numbers `left` and `right` and another number `k`, find maximum `a XOR b` less than or equal to `k` such that `left <= a < b <= right`.

One solution is to check all the pairs, but I feel there must be a constant time solution.

I know how to find a pair with maximum XOR value in constant time, is it somehow related to this problem?